# Execution life cycle of MXML+actionScript files

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flexbuilder

I know that When we compile a Java class then it will convert it into `.class` file and then through this `.class` file we have been able to run our code
Now I am new to Flex4 and ActionScript3 and I want to know what happened when I create a MXML file in flex builder and run it.
Is MXML file first convert to `.as` file and the able to run or some other conversions happen?

Answer (score 0):

> Is MXML file first convert to .as file and the able to run or some other conversions happen?

Yes, the mxml compiler will convert MXML files into Actionscript classes. The mxml compiler generates a lot of code, which by default is not saved in your project. You can, however, add the `-keep-generated-actionscript` option (or just `-keep`) to the compiler options of your project you can see the generated code.

Here is a [reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html) to the various compiler options. Right click your project in Flash Builder, select "Properties", and select "Flex Compiler" to see/edit the compiler options.

Comment: so what happened after the conversion of `.as` files

Comment: After generating the Actionscript classes, the compiler generates byte code in the form of a SWF file (or SWC file for library projects). Like Java, Flash Player executes the byte code in your SWF.